# Why does setting the button background through the style theme not work?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to set background drawable for my Button.

When I set it directly inside Button everything works fine.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>
```

[image]

But when I try set it with style it doesn't work.

```
<style name="SingInButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_height">120dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">250dp</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/button_background</item>
</style>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    style="@style/SingInButtonStyle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `android` prefix: `<item name="android:background">…`.